# Есть фон, нужно его размыть только в центре где контент

Tags: css, вёрстка, blur, css-filters

### **Как размыть только центральную часть фона ?**

Вот такой макетик, с размытием по центру фонового изображения, видел уже тут схожие вопросы, ответы однообразные и не отвечающие на вопрос, а просто ссылки на css фильтры и примеры применения его же, Если его применять к блоку размыт будет весь блок а нужно только центральную часть фона. 
 ***Помогите пожалуйста =)***

[image: Отмеченное синим размыто!]

Comment: Как вариант сделайте центральному блоку второй фон полупрозрачный с размытием и синевой..
а весь задний фон запихните в блок на уровень выше по вложенности
и будет вам счатье

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/800/600) repeat-y center top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mask {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/800/600) repeat-y center top;
  height: 105%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  filter: blur(10px) hue-rotate(210deg);
  z-index: 0;

  min-height: 600px; /* для примера */
}

.container {
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask"></div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть один минус, background: cover не поставишь либо репит либо ставить большую картинку и подгружаешь каждый раз уменьшенную версию в media) если есть лучше мысли как то же самое сделать адаптивно буду рад услышать, Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Хотя нет можно и з background: cover вот пример может кому то пригодиться.

Comment: ссылку на пример не забудьте вставить, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Хотел с codepen вставить, но не уверен что там без регистрации код сохраняется) надо будет протестить) хороший сайт) "Єто не реклама" =)

Answer (score 0):

Контейнеру фон, центральному блоку overflow:hidden и внутрь него еще один фон уже с размытием, абсолютное позиционирование чтобы разместить размытый фон точно там где и не размытый и они вместе масштабируются. Всем спасибо за ответы!
 ***Код на случай если кому пригодиться:***

```css
.container{
  margin: 0 auto; 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: url("https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/579fb6ee4b46415647e292e4.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}

.blur{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}

.bg{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/579fb6ee4b46415647e292e4.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blur">
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```